# Inline Child Processes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, web-worker, child-process

I'm familiar with Web Workers in the browser and figured that the Node.js equivalent of doing

```
const worker = new Worker('./worker')
```

is

```
const worker = child_process.fork('./worker')
```

The API is a bit different, and they don't quite work the same under the hood but in the end Web Workers and Child Processes seem to both do roughly the same thing; allow you to run JavaScript code in parallel.

Now, there is this neat thing that can be done with Web Workers where instead of creating a Worker by passing the path/url of the file containing the worker code you can pass an actual function. This can be achieved with this simple three line function:

```
function createWorker(fn) {
  var blob = new Blob(['self.onmessage = ', fn.toString()], { type: 'text/javascript' });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  return new Worker(url);
}
```

This allows you to write your worker code inline, in the main/master/parent (whatever you wanna call it) file, like this:

```
var myWorker = createWorker(function (e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data.toUpperCase());
});

myWorker.onMessage = function (e) {
  console.log(e.data); // HELLO FROM AN INLINE WORKER!
}

myWorker.postMessage('hello from an inline worker!')
```

**QUESTION**
How can I achieve the same thing with Node.js Child Processes? I couldn't tell from looking at the documentation whether or not you could pass something other than a module path to child_process.fork or if there was any other way to achieve what I want; to write inline child processes.

**UPDATE**
I have tried the following, based on @Bergi 's suggestion in the comments:

```
const fileSync = require('tmp').fileSync;
const writeFileSync = require('fs').writeFileSync;
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

function createWorker(fn) {
  const tmpobj = fileSync();
  writeFileSync(tmpobj.name, fn.toString()); 

  return fork(tmpobj.name);
}

var myWorker = createWorker(function (e) {
  process.send(e.toUpperCase());
});

myWorker.on('message', function (e) {
  console.log(e); // HELLO FROM AN INLINE WORKER!
})

myWorker.send('hello from an inline worker!');
```

Alas, I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\phili\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-165566BgqUKKM5yjR.tmp:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function (e) {
                                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I'm afraid I am out of my depth here. Any idea what is going on and how I can get it to work?

Comment: interesting question. IMHO, I don't think all the thing which is implemented in frontend JS ( as Web Worker), also work in Backend JS (NodeJS).

Comment: "*where you can pass an actual function*" - not really, you're still passing a string. You just [create the string from a function body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) - it's a hack.

Comment: `var n = require("tmp").tmpNameSync(); require("fs").writeFileSync(n, fn.toString(); require("child_process").fork(n)` should have about the same effect

Comment: @Bergi you are right, of course. I will give your solution a try.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the question after trying your suggestion but I'm getting an odd syntax error. Take a look, what do you think is going on here?

Comment: It's creating a file with the literal content `function (e) {
  process.send(e.toUpperCase());
}`. Which is not a valid script, with its name-less function declaration. Similar to the webworker hack putting the function code in a position where it is interpreted as a message handler to be installed, we need a way to make the code run. An IIFE might do it (`writeFileSync("("+fn.toString()+")();");`), but you might to give it some kind of runtime (hooking it directly into the IPC or so).

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to install a termination listener on the child process which will delete the temp script file. Also, a disclaimer: this is a hack and might be a security hole - one should not run executable code from the tmp directory, at least not without carefully managing file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
const fileSync = require('tmp').fileSync;
const writeFileSync = require('fs').writeFileSync;
const fork = require('child_process').fork;



function createWorker(fn) {
  const tmpobj = fileSync();
  writeFileSync(tmpobj.name, `process.on('message', ${fn.toString()})`); 

  return fork(tmpobj.name);
}

var myWorker = createWorker(function (e) {
  process.send(e.toUpperCase());
});

myWorker.on('message', function (e) {
  console.log(e); // HELLO FROM AN INLINE WORKER!
})

myWorker.send('hello from an inline worker!');
```

A million thanks to @Bergi for his help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

With `worker_threads`, there's now an actual possibility to create threads through inline code without the need for temporary files (like shown by snowfrogdev).

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
new Worker(`console.log(require("process").env.HOME)`, { eval: true });
```

In this example, setting `eval` to `true` allows the usage of nodejs builtins too.